# Google Translate style select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I want to style an HTML select menu with CSS in a similar style to how Google does it on [Google Translate (translate.google.com)](http://translate.google.com). I have looked for tutorials online but everything used jQuery. **How can I make something similar to this but using CSS to style it?**

I hope you can understand my question and what I am trying to describe.

[image: Select menu from Google Translate]

Comment: try to use firebug and see "how" they did it

Comment: Here you have an example of DOM replacement with @KaneBlack s html structure; http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/EcxP3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What google does is have js build a completely different, and style-able html structure from normal dropdown box, which is then styled with css. Using click events on each of the languages a few hidden form elemnt values are edited as you choose new languages to translate between.

You can do the same with jQuery and some work.

I hope this clarifies how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make similar thing just with CSS then forget it - plain impossible. Google utilizes javascript for certain functions like when user picks language it gets selected and will have border and different background when user will try translation next time.

If you just want similar dropdown function, then check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GjxUX/)

Comment: This is good code, though I would avoid inline-block, you don't have to inlcude html & body elements on jsfiddle and use the 'TidyUp' function ;) +1. http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/GjxUX/1/

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I used inline-block just so that sub level would have shadow displayed and ULs would be in line. (Probably should have used float left on both ULs and .sub)